# encryption time using timer control in C#

Tags: c#, encryption

My problem that I want to calculate the encryption time in triple DES. I put a timer control in the form like shown below but the problem that it continue to count even the encryption is end. How can I stop the timer control in the way he counts the encryption time?

[image]

```
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();


          //3DES ENCRYPTION 

        MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tDES.Key = md5.ComputeHash(utf8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text));
        //to decrypt the data we must use these two property 
        tDES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tDES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        //this is interface to encrypt our data 
        ICryptoTransform trans = tDES.CreateEncryptor();
        encrypted = trans.TransformFinalBlock(utf8.GetBytes(textBox2.Text), 0, utf8.GetBytes(textBox2.Text).Length);
        textBox3.Text = BitConverter.ToString(encrypted);
```

Comment: Thats not what a timer does.  A StopWatch makes more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use a `Timer` for keeping track of how long something takes. `Timer` is set up to invoke code on an interval (say; updating that text box in real time).

[`Stopwatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) on the other hand is specifically designed for doing highly accurate timing of operations. You should use that in this case:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
//Operations
stopwatch.Stop();

TimeSpan duration = stopwatch.Elapsed;
//Do something with duration
```